# Why does multiprocessing not working when opening a file?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

As I am trying out the multiprocessing pool module, I noticed that it does not work when I am loading / opening any kind of file. The code below works as expected. When I uncomment lines 8-9, the script skips the `pool.apply_async` method, and `loopingTest` never runs.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


class MultiClass:
    def __init__(self):
        file = 'test.txt'
        # with open(file, 'r') as f:  # This is the culprit
        #     self.d = f
        self.n = 50000000
        self.cases = ['1st time', '2nd time']
        self.multiProc(self.cases)
        print("It's done")

    def loopingTest(self, cases):
        print(f"looping start for {cases}")
        n = self.n
        while n > 0:
            n -= 1
        print(f"looping done for {cases}")

    def multiProc(self, cases):
        test = False
        pool = Pool(processes=2)
        if not test:
            for i in cases:
                pool.apply_async(self.loopingTest, (i,))
            pool.close()
            pool.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    w = MultiClass()
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Script finished in {end - start} seconds')
```

Comment: What do you mean _it does not work when I am loading / opening any kind of file_?  How does it "not work"?  Do you get errors?

Comment: I edited the question a bit to try to clarify the OP's meaning. It looks like they typed "commented out" where they meant "uncomment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see this behavior because calling `apply_async` fails when you save the file descriptor (`self.d`) to your instance. When you call `apply_async(self.loopingTest, ...)`, Python needs to pickle `self.loopingTest` to send it to the worker process, which also requires pickling `self`. When you have the open file descriptor saved as a property of `self`, the pickling fails, because file descriptors can't be pickled. You'll see this for yourself if you use `apply` instead of `apply_async` in your sample code. You'll get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 36, in <module>
    w = MultiClass()
  File "a.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.multiProc(self.cases)
  File "a.py", line 28, in multiProc
    out.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

You need to change your code either avoiding saving the file descriptor to `self`, only create it in the worker method (if that's where you need to use it), or by [using the tools Python provides](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-state) to control the pickle/unpickle process for your class. Depending on the use-case, you can also turn the method you're passing to `apply_async` into a top-level function, so that `self` doesn't need to be pickled at all.